# Print value of a header into a TextBox

Tags: vba

I'm trying to loop through a range of cells until I find the cell i'm looking for.  When found, I want to note the column of that cell and print its heading, which is in row 2. The code would look something like:

```
For Each x in Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:AK20")
  If x.Value = sectionTbx.Text Then
    'print value of specific row in the column
    x.Activate
    MsgBox(Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column))
  End If
Next
```

I have tried using `&ActiveCell.Column`, quotations and saving ActiveCell.Column as a variable etc. This does not work, even though I managed to correctly print out `MsgBox (ActiveCell.Column)`.

I also tried incuding `.End(xlsUp).Offset(-1,0)` but for some reason, the cell it chose as the top cell would vary (I'm implementing a search and return macro into someone else's spreadsheet table, I think they may have formatted it badly and that's affecting xlsUp somehow.)

How can I print the value of the header into a TextBox in the user form? I am only able to get it to print "True" into the box. I assume this is a data type issue but I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a find loop is much faster than iterating through each cell individually:

```
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim strFirst As String

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:AK20")
    Set rngFound = .Find(sectionTbx.Text, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            MsgBox .Parent.Cells(2, rngFound.Column).Text
            Set rngFound = .Find(sectionTbx.Text, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, although I would have just referenced `x.Column` instead of `ActiveCell.Column`.  Are you sure row 2 of the column where the result is actually contains the header?  As an experiment, try displaying `ActiveSheet.Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column).Address`; that will display the address of the cell containing the text that's being displayed with the original call.